# how to disable "profile" in monodevelop

Tags: ios, debugging, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, profiler

In monodevelop try menu > project > profile mono..., before try it, every works fine , but now is imposible for me debug in iphone debug simulator. always same error

In release simulator work fine 
In iphone real device work fine
In debug simulator the error:

I think disabled profile mono..., but is not posible, i dont know reason, Thanks.

```
Native stacktrace:

0   myprogram                          0x0009524c mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
1   myprogram                          0x0000bb38 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 248
2   libsystem_c.dylib                  0x9ae6059b _sigtramp + 43
3   ???                                0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
4   myprogram                          0x001a4a62 single_arg_user_copy_or_mark + 34
5   myprogram                          0x001ce400 mark_tls_slots + 128
6   myprogram                          0x001a81b0 scan_from_registered_roots + 336
7   myprogram                          0x001b4356 major_collection + 2886
8   myprogram                          0x001b5098 mono_gc_collect + 88
9   myprogram                          0x002233a6 monotouch_pump_gc + 38
10  libsystem_c.dylib                  0x9ae08ed9 _pthread_start + 335
11  libsystem_c.dylib                  0x9ae0c6de thread_start + 34

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use MonoDevelop's profiler you had to enable the SGEN garbage collector (GC). This is (from the stack trace) what's causing your crash.

You need to go back to your project's options (MonoTouch Build) and, under the Advanced tab, unselect the "Use SGEN generational garbage collector".

Once you have changed this, re-build your solution and it should work fine (the reason it works for release build is because the GC settings, like most of them, are kept separate between Debug and Release builds).

Now there's likely something broken because it should not be crashing like this. Would it be possible for you to report this issue (with a test case) to http://bugzilla.xamarin.com so our GC developers can get a look at what caused this issue ? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much!!  in the project options i go to iphone build> general tab, and i can see disable "Enable profiling" but checked, in Advance "Use SGen" is unchecked, then i Checked "Use Sgen" and go back General tab and now "Enable profiling" is Enable , then i  can unchecked > rebuild and is worked!!!, Thanks so much